# Returning push notification with each registered device's success status

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I am sending multicast `PushNotification`. But, instead of getting notification is sent to each device or not, I just got the total result like `"success":4,"failure":5`

```
{"multicast_id":5822472722938760042,"success":4,"failure":5,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1464161022787436%f6854ff1f9fd7ecd"}]}
```

I want to know which are devices that does not receive the notification.

Comment: is that the full response? If you send a multicast message to 9 tokens (devices) then you should get a response with a results array that has 9 items. However yours only has one item, a single "message_id" which is strange. If this is the full response could you also include the request you are making to send the multicast message?

Comment: @ArthurThompson i send to google apis gcm like this

`
  $fields = array(
    'registration_ids' => array(TOKEN_1,TOKEN_2,TOKEN_N),
    'data' => $msg
   );
  $headers = array(
   'Authorization: key=' . API_ACCESS_KEY,
   'Content-Type: application/json'
  );
`

Comment: Is that the full response in your question?

Comment: @ArthurThompson

$ch = curl_init();
   curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_URL, 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send' );
   curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POST, true );
   curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
   curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
   curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
   curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $fields ) );
  $result = curl_exec($ch );
  curl_close( $ch );
  echo $result;

and yes, that is the only response i get.

Answer (score 1):

This happens when your registered device ids are invalid and mismatched. So first cross check your device ids that are used to get notifications.